# AWS: FTP to S3 should I or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am setting up a number of FTPs. I have read that using EC2 to S3 using Fuse is not a good idea due to Fuse being 3rd party and security leakages. What is the more safer and recommended path: multiple buckets (one for each client) and FTP using Cyberduck or WinFTP Pro to connect to S3? Or are there other better ways this could be achieved (ideally at low cost). Thanks

Comment: Why do you need FTP? You can directly stream the files to S3 using AWS SDK right? The AWS SDK is available in different languages as well.

Comment: legacy reasons: clients have ftp already and we want to reduce costs of the existing OVH server. My initial idea was to go with EC2, point the ftp dns there keeping the clients accounts the same (then they don't have to do anything at all) to continue using ftp service.

Comment: Sorry, if I misunderstood anything here. If the files are in EC2 and need to be uploaded to S3, you can write Python script to upload the files to S3 directly (this doesn't require FTP at all). Appropriate permissions can be given to EC2 instance to connect to S3 bucket which is the highly recommended approach. FTP is not secure and it is not recommended in any commercial scenario.

Comment: Some examples:-
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

Comment: Thanks @notionquest, though that's not the issue. The issue to providing FTP access to a server or S3 for multiple unrelated clients. Currently we do this the traditional way with a OVH server. All the other services that were on the OVH server have been replaced with AWS through using Cloudwatch / API gateways / S3 buckets / Lambda functions. Only the FTP is left and then we don't need the OVH server any longer (quite a cost saving so far).

Comment: So to reiterate we have multiple external clients who use an FTP to store files on a server (in their own directories). In an ideal world our client s ought not to have to do anything their end to point to a new service. If I used a EC2 instance of some kind I could change our current DNS (ftp.our-website.com) to point to the new EC2 instance behind the scenes. The client will then not even notice that they are connecting to a different server as all the login info is identical. Does that make it any clearer?